# how do i change the width of my textbox in css?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, textbox

i added a asp.net textbox into my webpage and cover it with css like shown below

```
<tr>           
   <td id="policeprofileachievement" colspan="2" align="center">
            <b>Achievement :
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAchievement" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
   </td>
</tr>
```

In my source code i have added a width for the textbox. But in my css, i added this but it didnt resize my textbox width

```
#policeprofileachievement [type="text"] {

    position:absolute;
    margin-top:250%;
    left:0%;
    width:150px;
}
```

AND/OR

I removed the policeprofileachievement from my CSS and added this ( which is recommended by many )

```
#txtAchievement{
 position:absolute;
 margin-top:250%;
 left:0%;
 width:150px;

}
```

But there doesn't seem to have any changes on my textbox size either

Is there any other way to resize my textbox size?

Regards

Comment: you can simply target input field by `txtAchievement` id.

Comment: can you show me an URL containing your code? 
<asp:TextBox> is not standard HTML code and I wonder how many browsers support it

Comment: @LawrenceMok: it's clearly ASP.NET as indicated by the tags (the `asp:TextBox` is interpreted by ASP.NET at the server-side)

Comment: dont give width in both css and textbox code.It may collide with each other.Simply call your ID in css and mention your width in %.

Comment: you have to put a `width:auto` for your textbox if you want to just increase the size of your column.

Comment: @UpvoteMarkAnswer i realized this problem, removed it and added it in my CSS which doesn't work either

Comment: I ll post my answer below have a look..

Comment: @nneonneo Right. So I assume this piece of code is being interpreted by server, so we better look at the actual HTML code outputted so that we can create the matching CSS code.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan Could you also post the actual HTML code output here?

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan - If you don't want any workaround, you can try this: `textarea[id$='txtAchievement']{position:absolute; margin-top:250px; left:0%; width:450px; color:black;}`

Answer (score 2):

```
.txtbox
{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:250%;
    left:0%;
    width:150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  #txtAchievement{
 position:absolute;
margin-top:250%;
left:0%;
width:150px;
 }
```

Comment: hmm i tried this method but it didnt work though. I removed the height and the width from my source code and used this method but it still doesn't work. `        #txtAchievement{
width:150px;
height:300px;
 }`

Comment: It won't have that id as its an asp:TextBox

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you simply create a css class and add it to your textbox's cssclass property, like so..

```
.tb_style
{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:250%;
    left:0%;
    width:150px;
}
```

THEN ADD IT TO YOUR TEXTBOX LIKE SO

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAchievement" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="150px" Width="500px" CssClass="tb_style"></asp:TextBox>
```

This will also allow you to add same style to other TextBox(s) and create a constant look and feel to the webpage with minimal effort

Make sure you dont write some rule inline to your textbox thats also there in the cssclass...cuz your inline rule will override the rule in class.

Comment: Actually out of so many answers, this work the best. However i got a question is that my word "Achievements:" basically disappear when i added the Cssclass

Comment: You can try adding a placeholder in your TextBox like PlaceHolder="Achievements"..although its just a workaround....as for your disappearing word maybe certain css rules are making it disappear or maybe the text box is taking up 100% width and word is hidden behind TextBox...try setting the width of the column to something greater than 150px;....try removing the id selector #policeprofileachievement [type="text"]..or increasing width in this selector

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector `#policeprofileachievement[type="text"]` means "a tag with ID policeprofileachievement and `type=text`", which selects nothing because the `td` with `id=policeprofileachievement` has no `type` attribute.

You can use `#txtAchievement` to select the textbox because it has an `id` (no need to specify `[type="text"]`).

Alternatively, if for some reason you need to select multiple `text` input fields under `policeprofileachievement`, you could do

```
#policeprofileachievement input[type="text"]
```

Comment: i tried using the #txtAchievement which surprisingly didn't work as well.

Comment: It won't have that id as its an asp:TextBox

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

put **space** between     #policeprofileachievement and  [type="text"]

means style for inner all [type="text"] in #policeprofileachievement

```
#policeprofileachievement [type="text"] {

    position:absolute;
    top:250%;
    left:0%;
    width:150px;
}
```

Comment: actually i tried using the type="text" thing. but when i added it, my margin-top code didnt function.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan instead of margin-top use only top:25%;

Comment: unfortunately, it's still the same.

Comment: try to give margin or top in px

Answer (score 0):

CSS means cascading style sheet. So your css code block renders second but the text box that you have written already has a width component which will be 'cascaded' by the css you have written. Remove the css width property and your code should work.

With your present code try giving width below 150px. That may work.

Comment: I realized this problem and changed accordingly which unfortunately did not work.

Comment: Did you try removing `ReadOnly="true"` and check? and use `[type="input"]` in your css.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.It should work..For me its working..

**.aspx**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtAchievement" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" TextMode="MultiLine">  </asp:TextBox>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    #txtAchievement
    {
        width:50px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I highly doubt the tag <style> can actually be used in my css file in Visual Studio

Comment: For internal stylesheets its used.for external and inline no need to use <style>

Comment: this answer of yours is similiar to the one above which i tried and didnt work sucessfully. According to one's person comment, he/she says that #txtAchievement tag could not be used as the id belongs to a asp.net textbox. But nonetheless, i tried but eventually it didnt work.

Comment: No i did the same and tested.Its working for me.If ID doesnot work try it with CLASS.